# The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and absolutely continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The problem form Rudin RCA 7.12

Suppose $\phi: [a, b] \to R^1$ is nondecreasing.

(a) Show that there is a left-continuous nondecreasing $f$ on $[a, b]$ so that $\{f \neq \phi\}$ is at most countable. [Left-continuous means: if $a < x < b$ and $\epsilon > 0$, then there is a $\delta > 0$ so that $|f(x) - f(x - t) |< \epsilon$ whenever $0 < t < \delta$.]

(b) Imitate the proof of Theorem 7.18
(each implies the other two,

1.f is AC on I,

2.f maps set of measure 0 to sets of measure 0,

3.f is diffrentiable a.o. on I , $f' \in L^1$)

to show that there is a positive Borel measure $\mu$ on $[a, b]$
for which
$$
f(x) - f(a) = \mu([a,x)) \qquad(a \leq x \leq b)
$$
(c) Deduce from (b) that $f'(x)$ exists a.e. [m], that $f' \in L^1(m)$, and that
$$
f(x) - f(a) = \int_a^xf'(t)dt + s(x) \qquad(a \leq x \leq b)
$$
where $s$ is nondecreasing and $s'(x) = 0$ a.e. [m].

(d) Show that $\mu \bot m$ if and only if$f'(x) = 0$ a.e. [m], and that $\mu << m$ if and only if $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[a, b]$.

(e) Prove that $\phi'(x) = f'(x)$ a.e. [m].

I can prove (a) - (d), but failed on (e).
Can some me some hint about this.

Comment: Theorem 7.18 of what?

Comment: Is $m$ the Lebesgue measure on $[a,b]$ ? If so I believe the key is to use the equation from question c, you have $f(x) = \phi(x) [m]$ on the left-hand side, hence when you differentiate you get $\phi'(x) = f'(x)$ using that $s(x) = 0 [m]$. This should be checked carefully though.

Comment: Yes m is the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Are you familiar with the result that a monotonic function is differentiable ae. (confusingly known as Lebesgue’s theorem)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $D$ be the set of points on $I = [a,b]$ at which
$f$ is discontinuous (it is at most countable). Let $f$ be defined as follows in part (a)

$
f(x) = 
    \begin{cases} 
        \phi(x) & x \in I\setminus D \\
        \lim_{t\to 0} \phi(x - t) = \phi(x^-) & \text{else}
    \end{cases}
$

For the part in question (e) I proceeded as follows:

If $f'(a)$ exists then $a\in I$ is a continuity point of $f$ and by the definition of $f$ we can conclude that
$f(a) = \phi(a)$. Since $a$ is a continuity point we have that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that
$|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$, for all $x\in I\setminus D$ for which $|x-a|< \delta$.

Then from the definition of a differential transformation (7.22) and letting $0< h<\delta$, we have that
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        \lim_{h\to 0} \left| \frac{\phi(a+h) - \phi(a)}{h} - f'(a) \right| &= \lim_{h\to 0} \left| \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h} - f'(a) \right| \\
        &= |f'(a) - f'(a)| = 0
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Hence $\phi'(a) = f'(a)$. From part (c) we have that $f'(x)$ exists a.e $[m]$, hence $\phi'(x) = f'(x)$ a.e. $[m]$.